# Rising of fluid in U-tube manometer

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

> A manometer reads the pressure of a gas in an enclosure as shown in figure (a). When some of the gas is removed by a pump, the manometer reads as in (b). The liquid used in the manometers is mercury and the atmospheric pressure is $76\,\rm cm$ of mercury.
>
> [image]
>
> 1) Give the absolute and gauge pressure of the gas in the enclosure for cases (a) and (b) in units of $\rm cm$ of mercury.
>
> 2) How would the level change in case (b) if $13.6\,\rm cm$ of water are poured into the right limb of the manometer?

In this question part b when $13.6\,\rm cm$ of water is added, it is equivalent to $1\,\rm cm$ of mercury and, hence mercury in right, arm goes down by $1\,\rm cm$ and left arm goes up by $1\,\rm cm$. Thus new difference in level between the 2 tubes is $20\,\rm cm$.

However, the given answer is $19\,\rm cm$, presumably because the question designer may have just added $18 + 1 = 19$.

I have come across similar confusion elsewhere which makes me wonder whether  there is any critical point about a manometer which makes the level *difference* increase/decrease when fluids in general are added (rather than fluid in each tube), or is the answer wrong?

Comment: -1. The text in the image is not easily readable. It is not clear which part of the text relates to your question.

Comment: The picture is clear enough and it is clearly specified in the original post as"part b". Consider getting a decent pair of glasses(or maybe just a decent "pair")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book is correct.

If you were to add $1\,\rm cm$ of mercury on the right, the new level would be $\frac{1}{2}\,\rm cm$ higher, the old level (if you could track it) would be pushed down $\frac{1}{2}\,\rm cm$, and the other side would go up $\frac{1}{2}\,\rm cm$, and the difference would still be $18\,\rm cm$ between the tops of the columns – as it must be, because that is the pressure difference. It's the same result that would happen if both sides were open to the atmosphere.

The levels would still be the same on both sides after adding the $1\,\rm cm$, but they would each be $\frac{1}{2}\,\rm cm$ higher.

Now picture the original mercury in the problem as having the usual silver color, and the added $1\,\rm cm$ of mercury being red in color.

The difference in height between the tops of the two columns is still $18\,\rm cm$, as we have said. But the difference between the *silver* levels is $19\,\rm cm$ because the right hand silver level got pushed down $\frac{1}{2}\,\rm cm$ and the the left went up $\frac{1}{2}\,\rm cm$.

Now picture replacing the red mercury with $13.6\,\rm cm$ of water, and the silver mercury levels stay the same.